# CipherOutputStream cannot write to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a file, but I have a problem with `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`. I'm able to `encrypt` a file, but cannot be `decrypt` the file. I have try to close the Stream before CipherOutputStream. But ByteArrayOutputStream object remains zero and it does not conatin any bytes after CipherOutputStream. Any ideas? Many Thanks.

```
public static void encryptOrDecrypt(int mode, OutputStream os, InputStream is, String key) throws Throwable {

    IvParameterSpec l_ivps;
    l_ivps = new IvParameterSpec(IV, 0, IV.length);

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey,l_ivps);    
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey,l_ivps);            
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);                  
        doCopy(cis, os);
        System.out.println("Decrypted");
    }
}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    System.out.println("doCopy Step1");
    System.out.println("is: "+is.read(bytes));
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
        System.out.println("doCopy Step2");
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}

public static void writeFile(InputStream in){
    try {
        String strContent;          
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer sbfFileContents = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        while( (line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            sbfFileContents.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("File:"+sbfFileContents);            
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
os.close();

CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
```

You are flushing and closing outputstream and THEN using it in `CiptherOutputStream`

Create `CiptherOutputStream` before that.

Comment: I have tried to close and flush the outputstream after CipherOutputStream. But the object remains zero.

Comment: @XoXo: Could you post your updated code? Also, include the code for doCopy method.

Comment: @XoXo: Where is it? Edit your question and add updated question there.

Comment: @XoXo: There are two places where you have created CipherInputStream, at one, you have corrected the issue that i mentioned, at the other place you are still calling doCopy(cis, os); after os.flush and os.close is already called.

Comment: Even I remove the flush and close inside docopy. Object still remains zero. There are two CipherInputputStream, because one for encrypt, another ones for decrypt.

Comment: @XoXo: Can you check that your code is actually going in the while loop for decryption?

Comment: yes checked and the coding loaded inside the loop. because console displayed "Decrypted"

Comment: console will always display "Decrypted" unless there is any exception in doCopy. Write a sysout inside the while method in doCopy method and check if it is bein displayed or not.

Comment: There is no exception throw. I have added sysout and return doCopy Step1
is: -1

Comment: @XoXo This means that the is.read(bytes) is not returning anything (-1). Please check in your code what inputstream and outputstream variable is it passing. Are you sure that encrypt was done successfully?, how are you ensuring that?

Comment: I have checked the inputstream that have value. once passed CipherInputStream then the value is empty. When I encrypt the file, its successful, because there is a file generated with encrypted message inside the file.

Comment: @XoXo 1) Check if the inputstream passed in case of decrypt is correct or not. 2) Try using .read() method instead of .read(bytesbuffer). Print what you are getting from .read() method.

Comment: I have tried to read the inputStream from encrypted file and showed ecncrypted message. I'm sure before CipherInputStream have value. Once passed the CipherInputStream the return value is empty. I was thinking whether is the ByteArrayOutputStream with CipherInputStream problem. That's why thinking whether is Flush or close problem before CipherInputStream.

Comment: @XoXo: Just checking, sure you have removed that code now, where you are read the inputstream to show encrypted message? Inputstream from a file could be read only once, after that its pointer is at the end of the file. You should only read inputstream in the doCopy method. That might be the problem.

Comment: I have updated the coding. The inputstream should be for cipherInputStream, right?

Comment: @XoXo: As written earlier, check 1) That you are reading from your inputstream only ONCE. 2) Try .read() method instead of buffered read and print the output. 3) Close inputstream after your doCopy method exits.